# Can I buy a development card in the special building phase?

Tags: catan, expansions

Can I buy a development card in the special building phase that occurs between player turns?

Comment: the special build phase inbetween turns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes.

Taken from the  5-6 players rules pdf: http://www.catan.com/files/downloads/settlers_5-6_rv_rules_100107.pdf

emphasis mine:

> • Special Building Phase – Your opponents may build as outlined below. The
>   Special Building Phase occurs just after the end of your turn (i.e.,
>   between player turns). All the other players may participate in the
>   Special Building Phase. **Each player then takes his turn clockwise
>   around the table, and is allowed to build anything he can create with
>   his resources**. 3 Note that no player is allowed to play Development
>   Cards during the Special Building Phase. Also note that players are
>   not allowed to do any trading with other players—nor are they allowed
>   to use Maritime Trade—during this phase. They may only use the
>   resources they have in their hands. For this reason, players are
>   advised to trade as much, and as advantageously, as possible with the
>   current player during his trading phase. They will then have the
>   resources they need to build during the Special Building Phase. **The
>   Special Building Phase is an opportunity for all the other players
>   (who are not currently taking their turn) to build roads, settlements,
>   and cities, and/or to buy Development Cards.** This phase allows each
>   player to influence the game, even though it is not his turn! ...

This is also supported by the [catan faq](http://www.catan.com/faq-page/93):

> Development Cards in General - **If I have bought a Development Card
>   during the special building phase** right before my turn, may I play
>   this card on my turn?
>
> Yes.